# Unable to upload a pdf document using dr chrono api via php cURL

Tags: php, pdf, curl, drchrono-api

I am using php curl to upload pdf document using in dr chrono using api/documents.  Actually I am not clear on how to pass my pdf file so that it gets uploaded.

Here is my params array

```
$handle = fopen('pdfsPatientInformation_1446467593.pdf', 'r');
$myfile = fgets($handle);

$docParams = array('doctor' => 7891,'patient' => 58001561,'description' =>'Patient Medical History Form','date' => '2015-02-11','document' => $myfile);
```

I am getting error

> {"document":["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]}

Please can you help me with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're POSTing with the encoding "multipart/form-data"

With PHP CURL:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $THE_REMOTE_URL_YOU_ARE_POSTING_TO);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'document' => "@/Users/username/Desktop/test.pdf",
    'doctor' => "7891",
    'patient' => "58001561",
    'date' => "2015-11-02",
    'description' => "Patient Medical History Form"
  )); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

With HTML:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="doctor" value="7891">
    <input type="text" name="patient" value="58001561">
    <input type="text" name="description" value="Patient Medical History Form">
    <input type="text" name="date" value="2015-11-02">
    <input type="file" name="document">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Or with curl:

```
curl -F "doctor=7891" -F "patient=58001561" -F "description=Patient Medical History" \
-F "date=2015-11-02" -F "document=@/Users/yourusername/Desktop/test.pdf" https://drchrono.com/api/endpoint/here
```

Comment: thanks it works fine  now .Actually i  was not passing absolute path for the document instead i was using fopen.